# How do I safely stop a C# .NET thread running in a Windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I am maintaining some code which looks something like this.  It's a Windows service which does some work every 30 minutes.  The ActualWorkDoneHere method takes about 30 seconds to run, but if it is stopped while running it can leave things in a bad state.  What is the best way to prevent that from happening?  Should I replace the While(true) with a boolean which is set to false in the onstop method (removing the thread Abort call)?  Is there some way to tell if a thread is sleeping?

```
namespace WorkService
{
    public partial class WorkService : ServiceBase
    {
        private Thread _workerThread = null;

        public WorkService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork));
            _workerThread.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            _workerThread.Abort();
        }

        static void DoWork()
        {
            int sleepMinutes = 30;

            while (true)
            {
                 ActualWorkDoneHere();

                 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, sleepMinutes, 0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a job for Task Scheduler!  :)

Comment: @Greg Doesn't the Task Scheduler run on a schedule? In this case Stimy is looking to pause for 30 minutes and then run again, not run every 30 minutes regardless.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When I have something like this, I usually use a `ManualResetEvent`. This is set in the `Stop()` call. Then I wait with a timeout:

```
for (;;)
{
    if (_stop.WaitOne(timeout))
        break;
    DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: +1 Also, if you can stop DoSomething() at a few points without leaving the data in an inconsistent state, you could do an `if (_stop.WaitOne (0)) { ...return...}` there to avoid waiting up to 30s.

Comment: +1 And i use a ManualResetEvent to fire a signal when the thread really stops. So the stop method waits for this signal after it tells the thread to stop.

Comment: You don't need an event to tell you when the thread stops; just call Thread.Join.

Comment: If you're on .NET 4.0, you can use a `CancellationToken`.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing it yourself is the only safe option. Even if you find a way to find out if a thread is sleeping, you will still have a race condition if you try to kill it (because it potentially starts processing after you check and before you kill it).

Instead of Thread.Sleep you could e.g. sleep 500ms and check if the abort flag is still false, sleep another 500ms etc. before 30mins passes, then do the job, etc. (this would be a pragmatic approach). If you want something more elegant, you could use a ManualResetEvent with a timeout to wait for the main thread signalling that its time to abort.

Answer (score 2):

Wow everyone makes this so complicated.  Use a Timer:

On races:
The original post had a race in OnStop which has been fixed.  As far as I know putting the service into a stopped state will not abort threadpool threads which are used to service the timer.  The condition of the timer firing and the service being stopped at the same time is irrelevant.  ActualWorkDoneHere() will either run, or not run.  Both are acceptable conditions.

```
namespace WorkService
{
    public partial class WorkService : ServiceBase
    {
        protected const int sleepMinutes = 30;
        protected System.Timers.Timer _interval;
        protected bool _running = false;

        public WorkService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _interval = new System.Timers.Timer();
            _interval.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            _interval.Interval = sleepMinutes * 60 * 1000;
            _running = false;
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _running = true;
            _interval.Enabled = true;
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            _interval.Enabled = false;
            _running = false;
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(_running)
                ActualWorkDoneHere();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if anyone still feels that theres a race condition please explain.

Comment: @JeffreyABecker by default the timer may run more than one thread simultaneously, therefore the possibility of race conditions exist.  The ManualResetEvent always will run by default on one thread.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.  Add the following variables to your class:

```
private readonly object syncObject = new object();
private bool stopping;
private bool stopped = true;
```

Then in OnStart, you do something like this (I have a helper method which does some logging in this example, and the "Run" method does the actual work).:

```
    public override void OnStart()
    {
        while (stopping)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(MSECS_SLEEP_FOR_STOP);
        }

        lock (syncObject)
        {
            // make sure task isn't already started
            if (!stopped)
            {
                Helper.WriteToLog(logger, Level.INFO,
                    string.Format("{0} {1}", TASK_NAME, "is already started."));
                return;
            }
            stopped = false;
        }

        // start task in new thread
        Thread thread = new Thread(Run);
        thread.Start();

        Helper.WriteToLog(logger, Level.INFO,
            string.Format("{0} {1}", TASK_NAME, "was started."));
    }
```

Your "Run" method, which does the work of the thread, would look like this (processInterval would be how long you want to wait between runs, you could set it in the constructor or just hardcode it):

```
    private void Run()
    {
        try
        {
            while (!stopping)
            {
                // do work here

                // wait for process interval
                DateTime waitStart = DateTime.Now;
                while (((DateTime.Now - waitStart).TotalMilliseconds < processInterval) && !stopping)
                {
                    // give processing time to other threads
                    Thread.Sleep(MSECS_SLEEP_FOR_CHECK);
                }
            }
            lock (syncObject)
            {
                stopped = true;
                stopping = false;
            }

            Helper.WriteToLog(logger, Level.INFO,
                string.Format("{0} {1}", TASK_NAME, "was stopped."));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // log the exception, but ignore it (i.e. don't throw it)
            Helper.LogException(logger, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), e);
        }
    }
```

Then in OnStop, you would do this:

```
    public override void OnStop()
    {
        lock (syncObject)
        {
            if (stopping || stopped)
            {
                Helper.WriteToLog(logger, Level.INFO,
                    string.Format("{0} {1}", TASK_NAME, "is already stopped."));
                return;
            }
            stopping = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lock object to prevent the thread being stopped while your work is actually happening...

```
    private static readonly object _syncRoot = new object();

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        lock (_syncRoot) 
        {
            _workerThread.Abort();
        }
    }

    static void DoWork()
    {
        int sleepMinutes = 30;

        while (true)
        {
             lock (_syncRoot) 
             {
                 ActualWorkDoneHere();
             }

             System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, sleepMinutes, 0));
        }
    }
```

You should be careful though - if your `ActualWorkDoneHere()` function takes too long, windows will report the service as failing to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an autoreset flag to handle stopping of the service. In that case you would not have to perform thread abort. Have added the sample code below

```
namespace WorkService
{
    public partial class WorkService : ServiceBase
    {
    AutoResetEvent serviceStopEvent = new AutoResetEvent( false);

        public WorkService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Thread workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork));
            workerThread.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
           serviceStopEvent.Set();
        }

        static void DoWork()
        {
            int sleepMinutes = 30;
        WaitHandle[ ] handles = new WaitHandle[ ] { serviceStopEvent };

            while (WaitHandle.WaitAny( handles))
            {
                 ActualWorkDoneHere();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Cheers,
Bharath.

Comment: -1 The AutoResetEvent will always be unset until stop and it will never run ActualWorkDoneHere().

Comment: Oops. Forgot to add the reset event in start.

Answer (score 0):

My service listens on a network socket so what I did is create a joined pair of network sockets and used the select system call to listen on both. If the joined pair reported ready to read I knew to shutdown the service.

This trick can be used to trigger an arbitrary number of threads to shut down so long as none of them actually read from the connected pair.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true)
        {
            if (m_reset.WaitOne(1,false))
                break;
             // DoSomething


        }
```

Please Try this inside `onStop()`